# Error: Unable to resolve module react-redux/native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am trying my first react-native application with Redux and on running the application on device getting below error message,

> "UnableToResolveError: Unable to resolve module react-redux/native from C:\project\Testing\index.android.js:
>   Module does not exist in the module map or in these directories:  C:\project\Testing\node_modules\react-redux"

package.json:

> {
>     "name": "Testing",
>     "version": "0.0.1",
>     "private": true,
>     "scripts": {
>       "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
>       "test": "jest"
>     },
>     "dependencies": {
>       "react": "15.4.1",
>       "react-native": "0.40.0",
>       "react-redux": "^5.0.2",
>       "redux": "^3.6.0",
>       "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
>     },
>     "devDependencies": {
>       "babel-jest": "18.0.0",
>       "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.1",
>       "jest": "18.1.0",
>       "react-test-renderer": "15.4.1"
>     },
>     "jest": {
>       "preset": "react-native"
>     }
>   }

index.android.js:

```
import React, { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux/native';
import App from './src/containers/App';
import configStore from './src/stores/configStore';
const store = configStore();
var TestingApp = React.createClass({
  render () {
    return (
      ...
    );
  }
});
AppRegistry.registerComponent('TestingApp', () => TestingApp);
```

Kindly assist to solve the issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [`index.js` of react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/index.js), you could get that `Provider` is exported by `react-redux` directly.

So you should use `import { Provider } from 'react-redux'` instead of `import { Provider } from 'react-redux/native'`.

You can also check the example from [here](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html#indexjs).

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.